# DLL out int not accepted

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have built a DLL in C#.

In the following function the IDE tells my that the function _api.Version has some invalid arguments. But I don't think that this is true.

```
    public int getVersion(out int uMaj, out int uMin, out int uBuild, out int uDev)
    {
        ApiError error;
        error = _api.Version(uMaj, uMin, uBuild, uDev); //IDE does not like this
        int iRet = (int)error;
        return iRet;
    }
```

The "Version" function is defined as follows:

```
    public ApiError Version(out int major, out int minor, out int build, out int device);
```

Does anybody see my error?
Thank you for the help!

The entire code of my DLL is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using B.Api;

namespace ABWrapperNET
{

    public class clsWrapper
    {
        someApi _api = new someApi();

        public int getVersion(out int uMaj, out int uMin, out int uBuild, out int uDev)
        {
            ApiError error;
            error = _api.Version(uMaj, uMin, uBuild, uDev);
            int iRet = (int)error;
            return iRet;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to the function, you need to prefix the variable names with `out`.

I would guess this requirement is for readability purposes. Normally a programmer would not expect an integer being passed to a function to be modified, so if `out` or `ref` weren't there, the variable being modified would be a huge surprise.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why this is so? There is no other option available, so C# should know how to handle this. Or is it for good readability?

Comment: Incorporated into answer

Comment: @tmighty technically it could be done automatically (unless overload resolution becomes problematic), but it changes the meaning quite significantly, so I fully support the language designers choice to make it explicit - makes it obvious whether we might expect the value to change during the call, and it makes "definite assignment" easy to see - in both cases, without needing to already know the full method signature.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, you need to specify `out` and `ref` modifiers at the *call site* as well as in the member declaration. That means that anyone *reading* the code is aware of what is going on. (This is a big boost to readability, in my view.)

So you want:

```
public int GetVersion(out int uMaj, out int uMin, out int uBuild, out int uDev)
{
    ApiError error = _api.Version(out uMaj, out uMin, out uBuild, out uDev);
    return (int)error;
}
```

Note:

- I've fixed the method name to follow .NET naming conventions
- I've removed the pointless declaration/assignment split for `error`
- I've removed the temporary variable for the cast to `int`; you could reintroduce this for debugging purposes if you want
- I would personally get rid of the `u` prefix on each method parameter, having something like:

  ```
  public int GetVersion(out int major, out int minor, out int build, out int foo)
  ```

... replacing `foo` with whatever the abbreviation "dev" is meant to represent.

You should also consider just returning a [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, and use exceptions for errors:

```
public Version GetVersion()
{
    int major, minor, build, foo;
    ApiError error = _api.Version(out major, out minor, out build, out foo);
    if (error != ApiError.Success) // Or whatever it uses
    {
        // You'd probably need to create this class yourself
        throw new ApiException(error);
    }
}
```